# Map a entity relation model to a relational database

Tags: mysql, database-design, mapping, relational-database, entity-relationship

I wanna map the following entity relation model to a relational database:

[image]

Whats the best solution for it? Shall I create a extra table like "CompanyEmployeeOffer" with all three table IDs to reduce the one to many relationships? Any other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think so. It's important try to avoid overthinking about performance, keep it simple until you need some of that (btw, your idea it's easily implemented on an already made software without major issues).

It's a clear diagram, simple, it's good to start (as far I know your complexity needs showed here).

Comment: FK constraints aren't relationships. In an ERD, `Offer` would be a many-to-many relationship if it uses a composite key of (Employee ID, Company ID). Also, ternary relationships are not the same as 3 binary relationships. Your table diagram can be implemented directly in any SQL DBMS once you decide what columns the tables must contain.

Comment: My question was not If I can implement it like in the diagramm. I wanted to know what's the the best solution for it. :-)